# How to get iOS Safari to stream webm?

Tags: safari

How do I playback .webm on iOS Safari instead of downloading them?

When I serve the file with `Content-Type: video/webm`, Safari just tries to download it instead of streaming.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Safari doesn't support webm video. strangely, webm *audio* (but not video) support was added in iOS15, so one can theorize that Apple is planning video support in a future  release, but that's just speculation. (i guess one could try to send Apple an email and ask them, i haven't tried, because i doubt they would actually answer)

Comment: Apple [Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).